# Erro bootstrap video embed no modal

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4, vídeo, layout-responsivo, embed

Estou tendo dificuldades para incorporar vídeo do meu site no modal, coloquei um do youtube e deu certo mas quando tento por os meus em mp4 da erro.

Sei que o erro está aqui

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="assets/videos/flyer02.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Ja tentei usar as tags

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="assets/videos/flyer02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

e tambem nao carregou... já subi o site para ficar melhor de entenderem www.derlibatista.com.br , obrigado pela ajuda

```html
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modalflyersanimados" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="assets/img/close-icon.svg" alt="Close modal" /></div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <!-- Project Details Go Here-->
                                    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Flyers Animados</h3>
                                    <p class="item-intro text-muted">Flyer com áudio e animação.</p>
                                   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v64KOxKVLVg" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div> <br />
                                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="assets/videos/flyer02.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div><br />
```

Comment: Amigo. Testei os seus dois códigos aqui e os dois funcionaram. Tenta ver se o caminho do arquivo está certo ou se a extensão do vídeo é mp4 mesmo. Tenta também fora do modal pra ver se funciona.

Comment: Rodando no meu pc tmb funciona , mas na raíz do site não, coloquei fora do modal e tmb não apareceu, poderia ser algo com a versão do mp4?

Comment: Tenta com outro formato pra confirmar.

Comment: Realmente o problema era com o vídeo, obrigado pela ajuda  Gato de Schrödinger!

Comment: Que nada, brother. Você que resolveu.Abraço!